# Changing a background image repeat file

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, repeat

I was wondering if it's possible to change what file the background image repeats to when the old image runs out.

So, if image01.jpg is set as the first background-image, when it runs out vertically image02.jpq would be added as the background image to complete the page?

It might be a straight 'No', thts fine im just wondering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS3 you can have multiple backgrounds. You can specify a `background-repeat` for each of them. It is [supported by all major browsers](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=background), except IE8 and before.

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: 15% of your users are still using IE8 and up though... http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Depends on the website, and w3schools isn't that reliable per se. But indeed, many do. Fortunately it's a background. If you design it correctly, it will look good in most browsers and still be usable in IE8.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad solution, just that there are better ways to go about fixing it to ensure a higher degree of cross-browser compatibility :)

Comment: That's true, although you will need additional HTML to get it working. But if you do need support for IE8- too, you could choose to use nested divs, each one displaying a different background.

Answer (score 1):

There's always a solution for something in CSS if you're willing to add more markup to your file. Your best bet is to wrap the element you have the first image in with a containing div with the background you would like to appear if the first image runs out. Like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><span class="image"></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
  background: transparent url(image02.jpg) 100% 0 no-repeat /* Appears on the right */
  width: 200px; /* The maximum width */
  /* Can also add x pixels padding to ensure that x pixels of image02 are shown */
}

.image { 
  background: transparent url(image01.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; /* Appears on the left */
}
```

Of course you can always replace the `<span>` with an actual image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that HTML is an element, too.

```
html {/*insert tiling background image*/}
body {/*insert normal background image*/}
```

The body background will sit on top of the tiling html background. Works in every browser and won't require additional markup.